# Why does a JS array copied using "slice" is not equal to its source array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array of names as `let names = ['alex', 'mike']` and I make a copy of it using `let namesCopy = names.slice()`

Now `names == namesCopy` returns false. I don't understand why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `==` compares links to array objects, not arrays themselves. The `slice()` method creates a copy of the array. If you try to compare an array element by element, you will get `true`.

Also, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The [Slice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) does not modify the array. By definition, the `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

`slice()` copies object references into the new array. This new array object is a reference to the original array or a part of it. Both arrays refer to the same object and if it changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.

Here's a fun little example -

```
let cristiano = { country: 'portugal', club: 'real madrid'}
let messi = {  country: 'argentina', club: 'barcelona' }

let players = [cristiano, messi]
let playersClone = players.slice()

cristiano.club = "juventus"

console.log(players[0].club)
// Output - "juventus"

console.log(playersClone[0].club)
// Output - "juventus"
```

Similarly, since the reference can't equal the value, `names == namesCopy` returns `false`.

Conclusion - JavaScript can be cool but weird just as much?